# lodash how to test that object was assigned in

Tags: javascript, lodash

assume I have two classes:

```
function Class1(){ 
 this.prop1;
}
function Class2(){
 this.prop2;
}
```

then I use lodash assignIn method like this:

```
var object1 = new Class1();
var object2 = _.assignIn(new Class2(), object1);
```

the question is how can I test that object2 inherits from Class2 ?

Comment: You haven't assigned anything in `Class1` or `Class2`, `object2` is just an instance of `Class2` with no properties.

Comment: `object2 instanceof Class2 === true`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't initialize the properties in the object, no properties are created, so your object2 doesn't have prop2. At least you should initialize them to `null`:

```
function Class1(){ 
  this.prop1 = null;
}
function Class2(){
  this.prop2 = null;
}
```

As @Patrick Roberts says, you can use `object2 instanceof Class2 === true` to check whether object2 is "inherited" Class2.

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xie_qianyue/4fsejm70/).

Answer (score 1):

`Class1` and `Class2` are not classes.

The `instanceof` check suggested in another comment is orthogonal to `_.assignIn`.

`instanceof` returns `true` if the `prototype` of the right-hand value is on the prototype chain of the left hand value.